# Can I set Commerce to accept floats for quantity rather than just integers?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a specific requirement for a certain product type in Commerce to accept the line-item quantity as a float rather than an integer. Is this possible?

For example 5.34 rather than 5.

**The context**

- Product Type 'Tile' is sold in sqm (squared meters)
- User chooses required quality in sqm when they add to cart
- Drupal works out the minimum amount of tiles required for the chosen sqm value
- The sqm value is then adjusted based on number of whole tiles required
- Therefore sale price may be 5.12 sqm, if 5 sqm is required (because that is the specific sqm for X whole tiles.

Comment: quick fix: use sqcm ;)

Comment: Hey @Andre-B, this would be a simple fix but the standard for measuring floor space is sqm. From a UX perspective I think it would be very confusing for anyone ordering from the site to see or use sqcm. But helpful avenue solution nonetheless.

Comment: For reference. We did achieve this and were able to use Drupal Commerce cart and checkout to process orders that have line items with quantities to two decimal places e.g Tile A - 5.65sqm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal Commerce supports decimal quantities, there just isn't a UI based configuration mechanism for using that vs. integer quantities. You have to alter the Add to Cart form and Shopping Cart form to change the #datatype property on quantity text fields to 'decimal' (or whatever you prefer) and then add appropriate validate handlers to ensure valid decimal values are being submitted. Search the code for *datatype* and you'll see the integer example code.